# FileServer handler with some other HTTP handlers

Tags: go, http

I'm trying to start an HTTP server in Go that will serve my own data using my own handlers, but at the same time I would like to use the default `http.FileServer` to serve files.

I'm having problems to make the handler of the `FileServer` to work in a URL subdirectory.

This code is not working:

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "log"
        "net/http"
)

func main() {
        http.Handle("/files/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(".")))
        http.HandleFunc("/hello", myhandler)

        err := http.ListenAndServe(":1234", nil)
        if err != nil {
                log.Fatal("Error listening: ", err)
        }
}

func myhandler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        fmt.Fprintln(w, "Hello!")
}
```

I was expecting to find the local directory in `localhost:1234/files/` but it returns a `404 page not found`.

However, if I change the handler address of the fileserver to /, it works:

```
        /* ... */
        http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(".")))
```

But now my files are accessible and visible at the root directory.

How can I make it to serve files from a different URL than root?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to use the `http.StripPrefix` handler:

```
http.Handle("/files/", http.StripPrefix("/files/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("."))))
```

See here: http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#example_FileServer_stripPrefix

Comment: Oh, it was just below the FileServer example, I feel so dumb... Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The function [`http.FileServer`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#FileServer) produces an [`http.Handler`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Handler) that serves files from the specified directory. The result is just a handler that can serve HTTP requests, and when it is provided with one, it will look for a file whose path matches the request's URL **from within the specified directory**.

Your code registers the file-serving handler produced by `http.FileServer(http.Dir("."))` as the handler for all URL paths that start with `/file/`:

```
http.Handle("/files/", http.FileServer(http.Dir(".")))
```

An incoming request with the URL `/files/foo` will be delivered to this handler, which, in turn, will serve the file `./files/foo`. Instead, if you want the handler to serve the file `./foo` for the same request, you must remove the leading `/files/` from the request's URL before reaching the file-serving handler. That's what you achieve with [`http.StripPrefix`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#StripPrefix):

```
http.Handle("/files/", http.StripPrefix("/files/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("."))))
```

`http.StripPrefix` is a handler decorator: from an existing handler, it produces another handler that forwards its incoming requests to the original handler but these forwarded requests have the specified prefix removed from their URL paths.