# how to serve static files with http ? go

Tags: go

I'm using the snippet below:

```
fa := http.FileServer(http.Dir("attach/"))
http.Handle("/attach", fa)
```

The files are located into `/attach/` directory. However when I hit localhost/attach or `localhost/attach/anyfile`  it throws not found error

Comment: possible duplicate of [FileServer handler with some other HTTP handlers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541333/fileserver-handler-with-some-other-http-handlers)

Answer (score 3):

The `FileServer` handler serves the directory content from root, but the handler receives the full path from the request. If you are handling at a path other than `/`, you need to strip that prefix off.

```
fa := http.FileServer(http.Dir("/attach"))
http.Handle("/attach/", http.StripPrefix("/attach/", fa))
```

http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#example_FileServer_stripPrefix

Answer (score 0):

If the files are located under /attach then the pathname used with http.Dir() is wrong, unless the current directoy is /.